# Create array of lists with random values

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I’m trying to create sample data like the smpl_dt array example below.  I want to create an array where each element is a list of 8 random numbers between 0.0001 and 1.

I can easily create the list of 8 random numbers between 0 and 1 using:

```
Code:

[rd.uniform(0.0001,1) for _ in range(8)]
```

But I’m having trouble creating the array.  Any tips are greatly appreciated.

## Sample Data:

```
print(smpl_dt[0:5])

array([[0.0001, 0.0001, 0.3   , 0.0001, 0.2   , 0.0001, 0.2   , 0.3   ],
       [0.1   , 0.1   , 0.1   , 0.2   , 0.2   , 0.2   , 0.1   , 0.0001],
       [0.1   , 0.0001, 0.2   , 0.0001, 0.1   , 0.2   , 0.0001, 0.4   ],
       [0.3   , 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.2   , 0.1   , 0.2   , 0.2   , 0.0001],
       [0.2   , 0.3   , 0.1   , 0.0001, 0.2   , 0.1   , 0.1   , 0.0001]])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `size` argument. For example,

```
>>> arr = np.random.uniform(0.0001, 1, size=[4,8])

array([[0.67011692, 0.06662612, 0.13316262, 0.80666553, 0.88362879, 0.21492319, 0.22063457, 0.90038505],
       [0.87799324, 0.6486384 , 0.27700837, 0.54103365, 0.52688455, 0.93159481, 0.09245974, 0.54593494],
       [0.4680346 , 0.17802325, 0.21506341, 0.95917602, 0.20481784, 0.53165515, 0.1657028 , 0.39784648],
       [0.38951888, 0.03457946, 0.90076103, 0.13769038, 0.303991  , 0.57457931, 0.64236861, 0.85915101]])
```

Comment: Thank you, that totally did the trick!

Answer (score 1):

Without using numpy:

```
import random as rd

arr = [[rd.uniform(0.0001,1) for _ in range(8)] for _ in range(arrlen)]
```

Comment: I believe `rd` is a reference to `numpy.random`, so you're still using numpy anyway :)

Comment: @Tim Thank you, I tried doing something similar to this initially but I now see from your post that I needed to first turn it in to a list of lists, then turn that result in to an array.

Comment: @RafaelC It could be, but wasn't clear from the initial question.  Importing the built-in random module as rd works with this code as well.

Comment: @Tim its just that OP had tagged `numpy` arrays, thats why I guessed it was numpy haha ;}